# What is the name of the anime?

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon, toonami

This anime used to show on late at night on cartoon network/ toonami or adult swim. I want to say it showed somewhat early 2000's, but some time after 2003 or 2004. I can't recall if it was in english or Japanese. The show was about a boy who accidentally found a magic stone in a river that sent him somewhere else. There's a female. A princess, I think? She's in a coma or under a sleeping spell and lives in this robotic monster that if I remember correctly looks kinda like a robotic nessie  (the sea monster). She lives in the back of the robotic monster in what looks like a glass case. The boy and the monster and their friends are on a journey to pretty much wake her up. It was a very kid-friendly anime if I remember correctly.

Comment: I used to see Adult Swim all the time, 
but I don't recall a serie like that.  This is a list of all the animes on Toonami https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programs_broadcast_by_Toonami                               and this one on. Adult Swim with all the shows over the years
maybe it was not this channel  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programs_broadcast_by_Adult_Swim       maybe by reading the names you might recall it. Good luck. I checked most that I was not familiar with, but none were like the one you described.